# How to explain this sentence?

Tags: translation, mathematics

What is the best sentence to use instead of the following sentence:

> Fill up the output array, using the computed new value using -1 value from the calculation array as the index of the output array.

I'm trying to explain the process below. But I'm not sure what is the best sentences to do it.

---

**The Explanation:** 
Every element of an array has an index and value.
For example = array of [12, 59], has two elements. Index 0 has the value of 12 and index 1 has the value of 59. (or we can say 12 is at the index 0 and 59 is at the index 1)

Input array = [9, 7, 2, 1, 5, 7, 6, 4, 8] 
Calculation array = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9] 
Output array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

The Input array's first *value* is `9` and the Calculation array's *index* of `9` has the value of `8`. `9` is written at the index of (`8`-1=`7`) of the Output array. Then this process is applied to all elements in the Input array.

Input array = [**9**, 7, 2, 1, 5, 7, 6, 4, 8] 
Calculation array = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, **9**] 
Output array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, **9**] (9 is written at the index 8 [because 9-1=8])

Input array = [9, **7**, 2, 1, 5, 7, 6, 4, 8] 
Calculation array = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, **7**, 8, 9] 
Output array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, **7**, 0, 9] (7 is written at the index 6 [because 7-1=6])

Input array = [9, 7, **2**, 1, 5, 7, 6, 4, 8] 
Calculation array = [0, 1, **2**, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9] 
Output array = [0, **2**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 9] (2 is written at the index 1)

and final result is : 
Output array = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply say

> Given an input array and calculation array, output an array, using the `n`th *value* of the input array to be value `i`, and get the index of that `i` value in the calculation array, before putting the value `i` into index [`index of i (calculation array) - 1`] in the output array.

Extremely wordy though, you can split up the sentence if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is a valid question for this site. It might be better asked in a more technical forum.

Did you notice that the input array and calculation array in your example have a different number of elements?

I’d use labels and math notation. Without assistance, a natural language cannot cope with this kind of technical exactitude.

> Letting p_i be the value in the input array with index i, q_j be the value in the calculation array with index j, and r_k be the value in the output array with index k. Set the value of r_k to the value of p_i, where k is equal to q_(p_k) - 1.

Comment: Btw, this is a sorting algorithm, that sorts the **input** values with the help of the **calculation** array. The **output** array has sorted values. For more detail: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/